# Opening div that is clicked with popup

Tags: angularjs

Issue is all my divs open on `click`.

I want only that div to open with its content which is clicked.

`openBigDiv` function is :

```
$scope.IsHidden = true; 

$scope.openBigDiv = function {
    $scope.IsHidden = $scope.IsHidden ? false : true; 
}
```

I am calling function in div using `ng-click`.

Comment: Can you post the html as well?

Comment: Please find my Html <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 checkContent" ng-repeat = "appreciate in CustAppre" ng-click = "openBigDiv()"><div class="quote-inner-wrapper"><div class="arrow_box blue-texture-bg custApprPopOver"><blockquote class="no-bg white quotation-white"><p>{{appreciate.appre}}</p><span class = "hideContent">{{appreciate.custContent}}</span></blockquote> </div>
                        <a role="button" class="customerName blue" href="#">{{appreciate.by}}</a>        
                    </div>
                </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use visibility flag array

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        <div>
            <button ng-click="showElem('elem1');">Show elem1</button>
            <div ng-show="IsElemVisible('elem1')">elem1</div>
            <button ng-click="showElem('elem2');">Show elem2</button>
            <div ng-show="IsElemVisible('elem2')">elem2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or HTML if you want to use looping :

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-init="myElems=['elem1','elem2','elem3']">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        <div ng-repeat="elem in myElems">
            <button ng-click="showElem(elem);">Show {{elem}}</button>
            <div ng-show="IsElemVisible(elem)">{{elem}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testController', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $log) {
    $scope.hiddenElements = [];
    $scope.IsElemVisible = function(elemId) {
        return $scope.hiddenElements[elemId];
    }
    $scope.showElem = function (elemId) {
        $scope.hiddenElements[elemId] = true;
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqeses2r/)